# redirect on another page on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a web app and I have 2 textboxes and one button with an input field

```
<input id="Login" type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("loggedin","logincontroller")'" style="" width="200" height="34" value="submit" />
```

and my controller looks like

```
public ActionResult loggedin(string role, string username, string password)
{
    webservice.loginservice a= new webservice.loginservice();
    a.getlogintype(role, username, password);
    return View();
}
```

with my webservice

```
[WebMethod]
public string getlogintype(string role, string username, string password)
{
    string strtru="";
    string strfalse="";
    sqlcon;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [admin] where userid='" + username + "' and pass ='" + password + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        strtru = "true";

    }
    else
    {
        strfalse = "false";

    }
    con.Close();
}
```

My controller is calling the webservice and now I want to know how to redirect the page on successful validation. This is my first application using mvc I know there are many mistakes in this app(please let me know all the mistakes).

I am creating the application on mvc 5 and I am only using input fields not `@Html` syntax because I want to design it like([beta2.hti-india.com](http://beta2.hti-india.com)) this app is created by me on asp.net c#.

Comment: if(a.getlogintype(role, username, password) == "true"){ RedirectToAction("action","controller") }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your web service code looks good.

changes in your code.

```
public ActionResult loggedin(string role, string username, string password)
{
 webservice.loginservice a= new webservice.loginservice();
 string result = a.getlogintype(role, username, password);
 if(result == "true")
 {
   // redirect to your application home page or other page
   return RedirectToAction("OtherAction", "Controller");
 }
 else
 {
   return View();
 }  
}
```

try to use this is better way for **.cshtml** or **View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("loggedin", "controller", new { ReturnUrl = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

<!-- your textbox here-->

    <input id="Login" type="submit" value="submit">

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your action method loggedin(..) you should return a new view by using RedirectToAction()

```
return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController");
```